# Advanced "find" in Sublime Text 2

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

I enjoy the [advanced find features of vim](http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html) such as:

`/joe/s-2` which sets the cursor "to start of match minus 2"

Is there a way to accomplish this in Sublime Text 2, using native functionality or an existing plugin?

I'm aware of [Vintage Mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) and [VintageEx](https://github.com/SublimeText/VintageEx), the latter of which gives you command line vim, but returns "No Range Allowed" error if `/joe/s-2` is attempted.

Comment: No. If VintageEx can't, I'm afraid there's no way to do that. Might I suggest you use Vim instead?

Comment: haha, what about all the eye candy?! good point though. i am weighing the two options heavily. +1

Comment: If ST2 existed back when I searched for a cross platform TextMate replacement, I honestly think I'd have chosen it over Vim. It's obviously easier to pick up and closer to where my expectations were back then. Now that I feel very comfortable in Vim, I just can't imagine working even one hour with ST2 or TM: both are so underpowered compared to Vim or Emacs… it sounds almost like a joke. Even the eye candy is not very tasteful in ST2 IMO.

Comment: Or you could file a bug on https://github.com/SublimeText/VintageEx; even better, make a pull request.

Comment: @jpfuentes2, thanks for the advice to post a bug report.  yea i'd love to contribute as well. have to learn python first though. :)

Comment: Press arrow thrice, it should do. If you want a better solution, look how vintage is made, dig into api and some simple plugins for a bit, you don't need to learn python beforehand, it's quite straightforward. Just remember that indentation matters. Actually the key settings are usually more important than the python part, look there and in one evening, you should have it.